# What "A small town girl with big city dreams" means?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

Can you please explain to me this sentence? I can't understand it :(

Comment: Obligatory Journey reference: https://youtu.be/KCy7lLQwToI (first line at about 0:20)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Why was google not good enough for this? To post a question on this site you must include prior research. Take the [Tour] and see [ask] for more.

Answer (score 1):

The girl in question may or may not physically come from a small town but the connotation is that she is from a less sophisticated and less complex environment and has dreams of being more sophisticated and accomplished. This doesn't mean to imply that rural folk are any less sophisticated or accomplished than city folk.

Comment: Thank you very much so more or less is a girl who has big dreams,right?